# post checkbox value using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

how can i post the value of checked checkbox in php script, using ajax call i.e when the user click on checkbox the value is post to php script.

Comment: first take a look at this another post, I think you can adapt it for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816145/how-to-detect-that-a-user-has-unchecked-a-checkbox 
--- If you just need to print something else on the screen, whith the link above, change the <input> to an <? echo 'something to show'; ?>.. I think will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

put on checkbox onclick event:

```
<input type='ceheckbox' onclick='postwithajax(this)' />
```

and make a function like:

```
function postwithajax(e){
    //and here send with ajax e.checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to get values from html

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
     var myarray = [];
     $("#div input:checked").each(function() {
         myarray.push($(this).val()); //push each val into the array
      });
      // here post Array with ajax
  });
```

Html

```
<html>
 <head>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div">
  <input type="checkbox" value="one_name" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="one_name1">
<input type="checkbox" value="one_name2">
 <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
</div>  
<textarea id="t"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't override the bulit-in `Array` object, as it breaks many things. Changed it to `array`.

Comment: `$(document).load()` is invalid syntax. Use `$(document).ready()` instead. Or even better, just remove that (and be sure to remove the last `});` too), because it's best to place event handlers directly in `<head>`, before any events may trigger.

Comment: thanks for your replies @enthusiastic and @Nyuszika but i think you did't get my question my question is see there is a table populated from mysql and it also consists of checkbox value which is also populated from mysql table now if i want to check 2 more checkboxes than in that table than the value goes through ajax call to php script and update the relevant student table with that checkbox value. there will be no form no submit button the function will called upon onclick event of checkbox. So is it possible to do that if it is than how can i do....?