# update database on value change of activeCheckBox, Yii framework

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I have an activeCheckBox on a form and i want to update the database as soon as the check box value is changed.  I was reading the documentation on the CHTML class for the activeCheckBox but I dont really understand where to start.  Can anyone provide an example of how to setup the activeCheckBox with an ajax update or any links to examples?

**Edit**

Probably should mention that I just started working with Yii and have little experience with PHP and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

AJAX action in your controller:

```
public function actionCheckboxUpdate() {
  if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
  {
    if(isset($_POST['my_checkbox']))
    {
       // save value to DB
    }
  }
  else
    throw new CHttpException(400,
      Yii::t('app', 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.'));
}
```

Yii checkbox:

```
<?php echo CHtml::checkbox('my_checkbox', false, array(
  'submit'=>'mycontroller/checkboxUpdate',
  'params'=> array('my_checkbox'=>'1')
)); ?>
```

Depending on the params you want to pass in you may need to get fancier, like adding your own jQuery event listener which posts the actual value of the checkbox to your ajax action, but I hope this gets you started.

For more info, see the documentation for the [CHtml::checkBox](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBox-detail) (and the [CHtml::clientChange](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail) params that Yii uses to make AJAX simpler).

Here are some other articles that would be good to read as well:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/3337-activecheckbox-with-ajax/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/3110-ajax-and-sidebar
- [post checkbox value using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816309/post-checkbox-value-using-ajax)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create your checkbox as usual:

```
<?php
  echo CHtml::checkbox('my-checkbox', false, array('id'=>'my-checkbox-id'));
```

Then create a jQuery event listener

```
<?php
  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('my-event-listener',"
  $('#my-checkbox-id').change(function(){
      $.post(
          'controller/action',                 //url
          {                                    //data
               myval: $(this).is(':checked')
          },
          function(data){
               alert(data);                    //callback
          });
      });
  ");
```